# Error on running a certain simulation method on an open source software

Tags: windows-xp, simulation, memory-error

The software I am using is an open source geostatistics package called SGEMS. There are many simulation methods and many of them work fine, however when I am trying to use one multi-point simulation method then it shows me the general windows error along with the following error:

```
The instruction at "..." referenced memory at "...". The memory could not be "read"
```

My computer details are:

```
Microsoft XP
Professional
Version 2002
Service Pack 3

6400 @ 2.13GHz
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: The instruction at "..." referenced memory at "...". The memory could not be "read"](http://superuser.com/questions/186663/error-the-instruction-at-referenced-memory-at-the-memory-could-not)

Comment: @Heavyd - It's a duplicate but he is adding more info this time.  Last one was closed for lack of info.  Let's not discourage him :)

Comment: @JNK, the only difference I see is the title, looks like an exact dupe to me.

Comment: @heavyd - I see that now.  The original he EDITED after it was closed.  It was closed orignally because he had almost no info in it.  Take a look at the timestamps for closing and editing.

Comment: @JNK Instead of harping on whether it is a duplicate or not, why not **vote to re-open the original** and **vote to close this one**.

Comment: @heavyd Nice catch. I have closed the previous one as a duplicate of this one solely because this one has an accepted answer. In future, please vote to re-open the original as well.

Comment: @Diago - Apologies, I didn't mean to harp.  I saw the original thread get closed and this one opened with more info, so assumed it was fine to leave this one open since it was more complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the program: it's trying to access memory that it's not supposed to. (Strictly speaking it could be a bug in Windows, or a hardware problem, but they're a lot less likely.) This is a very generic kind of bug, so your best option is to report it to the authors (giving them the full data you've passed to the program — it's better if you can reproduce the bug with a small amount of input data — and the full error message).

Comment: I too suspect the problem to be related with memory. Thanks for the input, though I know it's hard to identify what's the problem.